# Display category name of custom posts only once in the loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a custom post type called "Projects" and for it some categories.

I would like to display the category name of the posts in the loop but only once.

I am using this but the category is being displayed on top of every post.

For example if the 2 posts are in the same cetegory, now I see the category name twice in the same loop.

How can I solve it?

My code:

```
<?php
  $category = the_category();
?>
<h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">
<?php
  if($i == 1) { 
    echo $category[1]->cat_name; 
  }
  $i++;
?>
</h2>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you initially set `$i` to `1` before The Loop and change `the_category()` to `get_the_category()` (`the_category()` prints category names - `get_the_category()` retrieves an array of category objects as your code expects). Also note that in PHP array indexes start at `0` - the first category object would be in `$category[0]`, not `$category[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

### Display category name of custom posts only once in the loop

Which page template do you want to display the category name? category page or single page,  I am pretty sure this code will work.

```
<?php
    $category = get_the_category();
?>
<h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">
<?php
    foreach ( $category as $key=> $val ){
        echo $val->cat_name .'<br>';
    }
?>
</h2>
```